# C# GUI to Arduino: Serial Data Not Working

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to send an integer through the usb connection to my arduino. When using the sketch monitor I can verify that the code works; However, when using the C# .NET GUI, I'm unable to get anything working.

I do know that the data is sending via the LEDs lighting up on the arduino.

I'm typing an RPM into a text box, converting it to 4 bytes (integer) and writing it. Here is the GUI code:

```
RPMMove = Convert.ToInt32(tbRPM.Text);
byte[] bRPM = BitConverter.GetBytes(RPMMove);
port.Write(bRPM, 0, 4);
```

On the arduino:

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.setTimeout(100);
}
void loop()
{
while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
      i = Serial.parseInt();
      stepper.setRPM(i); //move motor of other library
      //Serial.println(i); //I get the correct integer via the arduino monitor here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to send a return?  what exactly do you type in the sketch monitor?

Comment: I simply type either 5, 10 or 100 - any integer works. This variable sets the rpm of the motor attached.

Comment: Can you more clearly define the phrase "unable to get anything working?"

Comment: Perhaps this Japanese article and its comments will be helpful. [ArduinoでPCから、シリアル通信で数値を送る (Serial.parseInt())](https://qiita.com/yamanohappa/items/fda70aa430fb414be5d5)

Comment: When converting to an integer the order of the four bytes get swapped.

Comment: When i enter an integer into the arduino console, the motor moves. When i type the value into the GUI, iot sends, but the motor doesn't move. @robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` and the fact that it works when you type the number into the console both indicate that the device wants the string sent as text.  So do not use `BitConverter`, instead:

```
byte[] bRPM = Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes($"{RPMMove}\r\n");
```

You may need to adjust the line ending, naturally using the same one configured in your terminal emulator ("console") should work.

Comment: How many bytes would that be? Serial write requires port.write(bRPM, offset, no. bytes);

Comment: @Fraser: `bRPM.Length`

Comment: You're my saviour. I'll create a religion to celebrate your existence.